# Joint Probability of Four Coin Tosses

Tags: probability-distributions

**A fair coin is tossed 4 times. Let X be the number of heads in the first three tosses. Let Y be the number of heads in the last three tosses. Find the joint p.m.f. of X and Y . (Hint: There are only 2^4 = 16 equally likely outcomes when you toss 4 coins. If you are unable to calculate the probabilities using rules we have learned, just list all the possible outcomes!)**

[image]
I'm working on this problem, and getting the answer analytically as the hint suggests is pretty simple, but I can't seem to determine a closed form equation.

I have tried splitting it into some indicator variable type thing, where $f= first$, $m= middle two$, and $l=last$. And then $f+m =x$ and $l+m=y$.

I know that x and y aren't independent, so finding the joint p.m.f should be something like

$P(x \& y) = P(x) * P(y|x)$, and I have some weird equation that almost works, but it's certainly not right and I'd like two know how to properly do it.

Comment: Hard to say why or if it is not right without seeing it, but that is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear that there is a neat formula, but we can use indicator functions to get an ugly one.

Let $\mathbb{B} = \{0,1\}$ and $T_k \in \mathbb{B}$ represent the $k$th toss.

Write $X = (T_2+T_3) + T_1, Y=(T_2+T_3)+T_4$. Note that $T_1, T_2+T_3, T_4$ are independent and
$P[T_2+T_3 = k] = \begin{cases} {1 \over 4},& k \in \{0,2\} \\
{1 \over 2},& k =1\\
0,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

We can write
\begin{eqnarray}
P[X=x,Y=y] &=& P[T_2+T_3 + T_1 = x, T_2+T_3+T_4 = y]\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^2 P[T_2+T_3 = k, T_1 = x-k, T_4 = y-k]\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^2 P[T_2+T_3 = k] P[T_1 = x-k] P[T_4 = y-k]\\
&=& {1 \over 4} P[T_1 = x] P[T_4 = y] + {1 \over 2} P[T_1 = x-1] P[T_4 = y-1] + {1 \over 4} P[T_1 = x-2] P[T_4 = y-2] \\
&=& {1 \over 4} ( {1 \over 4} 1_{\mathbb{B}^2}(x,y)+ {1 \over 2} 1_{\mathbb{B}^2}(x-1,y-1)+ {1 \over 4} 1_{\mathbb{B}^2}(x-2,y-2))
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

$R_X = $ all possible values of $X$. But when we have $X,Y$, we have a joint PMF.
$$P_{XY}(x,y)= P(X=x, Y=y)
$$
The range will be $R_{XY} = \big\{(x,y):P_{XY}(x,y)>0\big\}$

The probability of all points must add to $1$:
$$\sum_{(x,y)\in R_{XY}}P_{XY}(x,y)=1
$$

Your question is not completely clear to me however. Normally joint pmf of random variable X and Y is usually given through a table or graph, or like you showed, simply solved by hand. The only thing I say you could try is the law of total probability:
$$
P_{XY}(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X=x, Y=y|N=n)P_N(n)
$$

It also may be helpful to note it's possible to find specific probabilities (for example, $P(X=0,Y\le1)$ like so:
$$P_{XY}(0,0)+P_{XY}(0,1)= {1\over16}+{1\over16}
$$